# WPMU Redirect user

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wpmu

On Wordpress Multisite I'm trying to redirect user after his permission level (permID) AND his site(virkID). So if the are normal user from site A, they get redirected to site A with permission level 3.

I have this code on a cutom loginpage:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submitlogin']))
        {
            $brugerUsername=$_POST['brugerUsername'];
            $brugerPassword=$_POST['brugerPassword'];

            $sql="SELECT * FROM virksomheder 
            INNER JOIN brugere ON virksomheder.virkID = brugere.virkID 
            WHERE brugerUsername = '$brugerUsername' and brugerPassword = '$brugerPassword'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
            {
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
               {
               $_SESSION['brugerUsername']=$_POST['brugerUsername'];
               $_SESSION['brugerPassword']=$_POST['brugerPassword'];
               $_SESSION['permID']=$row['permID'];
               $_SESSION['virkID']=$row['virkID'];
               $_SESSION['virkNavn']=$row['virkNavn'];
               $_SESSION['virkUrl']=$row['virkUrl'];
               $_SESSION['holdID']=$row['holdID'];
               $_SESSION['brugerID']=$row['brugerID'];
               $_SESSION['brugerCpr']=$row['brugerCpr'];
               $_SESSION['brugerNavn']=$row['brugerNavn'];
               $_SESSION['brugerAfd']=$row['brugerAfd'];
               $_SESSION['display_name']=$row['display_name'];
               $_SESSION['hoejde']=$row['hoejde'];
               $_SESSION['vaegtstart']=$row['vaegtstart'];
               $_SESSION['bmistart']=$row['bmistart'];
               $_SESSION['vaegtslut']=$row['vaegtslut'];
               $_SESSION['bmislut']=$row['bmislut'];
               $_SESSION['vaegtnu']=$row['vaegtnu'];
               $_SESSION['bminu']=$row['bminu'];    

            //REDIRECT USER WHERE virkID = '$virkID'
            /*<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<?php $row['virkUrl']; ?>/status/"> */


                    if (($row['permID'] == '3') and ($row['virkID'] == '1')){
                ?> 
                <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://mahogni.com/afs/status/"> 
                <?php
                    }  
                    if ($row['permID'] == '2'){
                ?> 
                <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://mahogni.com/afs/coachsite/">  
                <?php 
                    } 
                    if ($row['permID'] == '1'){
                ?> 
                <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://mahogni.com/afs/adminsite/">  
                <?php 
                    }   
               }  
            }
            else
            {           
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='2' height='45'>";
                echo "Ups! not correct";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";               
            }           
                }
            ?>
```

Can anyone tell me how its done??
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**not a real answer:**

Your code is filled with bad behaviour.

1. You don't escape you `$_POST` it is ripe for SQL injection.
2. You are using WordPress therefore you should use [`global $wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) for database connection.
3. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated don't use them, see above.
4. php redirections are done like this: `header('Location: http://yoururl.com/whaterver');`
5. WordPress has it's own user levels in the form of [Roles & Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) which can be set per site. There are plugins to make this more manageable.